# Why not spring amqp provider a sendAndAsyncReceive method signature?

Tags: spring, spring-amqp

Sometime we need send a message asynchronous and provide a callback when message result asynchronous returned.
Now,there is only blocking method sendAndReceive;why not provider a sendAndAsyncReceive method by pass a callback arg or return a listentablefuture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because nobody has asked for it.

You can use `send()` and configure an async consumer (`SimpleMessageListenerContainer`) to receive the replies.

Feel free to open a new feature [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP) or, even better, consider contributing.

**EDIT:**

[Here's a gist with sample code](https://gist.github.com/garyrussell/a9aa5e45e58ba4b79168).